# Why is Grid Layout causing android studio app to crash?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio-3.0, android-gridlayout

I am using android studio 3.1.4

The app crashes while exwcuting the following part of the code:

```
  GridLayout layer=(GridLayout)findViewById(R.id.gridId); //Crashes at this point itself.

        for(int i=0;i<layer.getChildCount();i++) {
            ((ImageView)layer.getChildAt(i)).setImageResource(0);
        }
```

Comment: could you post your error log

Comment: Yes, you need to add your error output

Comment: There isn't any error ;  during run time the app crashes at the point it is supposed to execute this part.

Comment: But then your logfile would give any response, right?

Comment: Have updated the question with error log.

Comment: Would you provide your code? Make sure you initialized everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is you use `android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout` in the `XML` file but `GridLayout` in the code.

to fix it, change this line

```
  GridLayout layer=(GridLayout)findViewById(R.id.gridId); //Crashes at this point itself.
```

to

```
 android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout layer=(android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout)findViewById(R.id.gridId); //Crashes at this point itself.
```

or just import `android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout`

Comment: Glad to hear that!

Comment: Replaced  " import android.widget.GridLayout; " with " import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout;  "    :)